# What are these potted plants with thin stems and leaves that look like sticks?

Tags: identification, succulents, cactus, cuttings

My mom gave me cuttings of this plant. She didn't know what it was but it seemed to do alright outside in the shade in Houston.

What is it?

*Click on pictures for closer view.*

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I like those 'coasters' .  For succulents/cactus you should never see water pouring out the drainage holes.  Shallow watering is important.  These plants have very shallow roots  and if the soil is wet below those roots it will stay wet.  This is the only time shallow watering is important.  If you ever add to your collection or propagate and need to buy another pot, get a shallow pot, wider than it is high.  Clay for sure, it breathes and helps keep the soil on the dry side.  Healthy looking plants, must be in a good spot for light.  Use bottled distilled water instead of tap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one; [drunkard cactus, little bottles](https://www.google.com/search?q=hatiora%20salicornioides&rlz=1C1QJDB_en&espv=2&biw=1067&bih=513&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjyhdzhh-HPAhXhwlQKHT1AC8oQiR4IgQEhttp://)

Let's see if this name works for this plant.  I like the drunkard part because it looks like lots of little bottles...grins!

Comment: Hatiora  salicornioides, agreed, its a forest cactus, which is why it does okay in lower light situations http://www.learn2grow.com/plants/hatiora-salicornioides/

Comment: Yayyyyyeee!  Thanks for agreeing.  I wish I had my library that is in storage 700 miles away.  Why is it more painful to read on the internet than flipping pages and reading from a book?  I must be getting old...miss books.

Comment: The name makes this plant even more attractive.  "drunkards dream" hilarious